# Ruby sum of elements from similar hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, hash

Suppose I have these records, where `r_years` could have any number of year keys:

```
Item.select('id','name','r_years').where(name:"N1")
...
"id" => 1, "name" => "N1", "r_years" => {"year2020" => "1","year2021" => "2", ...}
"id" => 2, "name" => "N1", "r_years" => {"year2020" => "2","year2021" => "3", ...}
...
```

How can I get the sum of the `r_years` values, for every year key, like this:

```
@r_years_sum = {"year2020" => "3","year2021" => "5", ...}
```

Comment: Is that the result of the query, or you're doing some transformation? Is `r_years` storing hashes?

Comment: Yes, that is the result of the activerecord query (looks like that with AwesomePrint). _r_years_ is storing a hash with the years values (it is a serialized Hash column)

Comment: Please read "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)".

Comment: _Sidenote:_ the data returned from the DB for numerics being indeed _strings_ is very clear sign of the poor design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
arr = [
  { "id"=>"1", "r_years"=>{ "2020"=>"1", "2021"=> "2", "2022"=>"3" } },
  { "id"=>"2", "r_years"=>{ "2020"=>"4", "2021"=> "5", "2022"=>"6" } },
  { "id"=>"3", "r_years"=>{ "2020"=>"7", "2021"=> "8", "2022"=>"9" } }
]
```

```
arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |g,h|
  g["r_years"].each { |k,v| h[k] += v.to_i }
end.transform_values(&:to_s)
  #=> {"2020"=>"12", "2021"=>"15", "2022"=>"18"}
```

The first step is:

```
arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |g,h|
  g["r_years"].each { |k,v| h[k] += v.to_i }
end
  #=> {"2020"=>12, "2021"=>15, "2022"=>18}
```

[Hash#transform_values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values) is then used to convert the values to strings.

This uses the second form of [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-c-new), which takes an argument that is referred to as the *default value*. `h[c] += 1` expands to `h[c] = h[c] + 1`. If `h` does not have a key `c`, `h[c]` on the right of the equality returns the default value of zero, yielding `h[c] = 0 + 1`.

Comment: Works well. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can map your result to get only the `r_years` values, and then use reduce and merge every value for each year and sum their value as an integer:

```
items.map do |item|
  item['r_years']
end.reduce do |acc, item|
  item.merge(acc) { |_, oldval, newval| (oldval.to_i + newval.to_i).to_s }
end
# {"year2020"=>"3", "year2021"=>"5"}
```

Comment: You could reduce memory requirements by skipping the mapping: `items.reduce do |acc, item|
 acc.merge(item['r_years']) { |_, oldval, newval| (oldval.to_i + newval.to_i).to_s }`.
end

Answer (score 0):

You can try this ...

```
arr = [
  { "id"=>"1", "r_years"=>{ "2020"=>"1", "2021"=> "2", "2022"=>"3" } },
  { "id"=>"2", "r_years"=>{ "2020"=>"4", "2021"=> "5", "2022"=>"6" } },
  { "id"=>"3", "r_years"=>{ "2020"=>"7", "2021"=> "8", "2022"=>"9" } }
]

res_hash=Hash.new(0)
arr.each do |x|
    x["r_years"].select{ |key,value| res_hash[key]+=value.to_i }
end
```